# jQuery - Usar duas funções juntas

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso que o mesmo método seja chamado em dois eventos, ou seja, no load da página carregar os dados, e caso o valor do input seja alterado carregar novamente o código.

```
($("#cpf_cnpj").load(function() or $("#cpf_cnpj").focusout(function()) {
     codigo
}
```

Como é a forma correta de fazer segundo a ilustração acima?

Comment: `.ready` é usado apenas no contexto de `document`, explique melhor quais eventos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#cpf_cnpj").on('load blur',validaCpfCnpj);

    function validaCpfCnpj(){
       // Script
    }

});
```

Pode ser feita assim:

1 - Cria a função independente de evento.

2 - Depois chama as funções que deseja pelo método `on`. Nesse caso ao carregar  página e ao sair do foco.

---

Outra maneira:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    validaCpfCnpj();

    $("#cpf_cnpj").on('blur',validaCpfCnpj);

    function validaCpfCnpj(){
       // Script
    }

});
```

Ps: sempre dê uma olhada no Inspect Element no Chrome ou no navegador que você usa para descobrir a presença de algum erro.

Comment: fiz como informou e não deu certo.

Comment: @Tiago, editei meu post. Tente a outra maneira.

Comment: Não tem um problema aí na ordem das declarações? A `validaCpfCnpj` não precisa estar no _handler_ do `.ready()`. Além disso, eu acho que `change` é um evento mais apropriado que `blur`.

Comment: Faz o seguinte, então @ctgPi: posta uma resposta ideal.

Answer (score 3):

Que tal

```
function myFunction () { /* codigo */ }

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', myFunction);
document.getElementById('cpf_cnpj').addEventListener('change', myFunction);
```

Eu botei o handler no `change`, logo ele só dispara quando o usuário alterou o campo *e* saiu dele. Se você quiser disparar toda vez que o usuário alterar o campo (mesmo ele ainda estando nele), você pode trocar por `input`; ambos são IE 9+.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/61f5cvjw/).